# Tengo problemas para mostrar diferencia entre 2 fechas PHP

Tags: php

Chicos, tengo la siguiente inquietud,

Necesito mostrar la diferencia de días entre 2 fechas, y hasta el momento he usado la documentación oficial de PHP, la cual me da el siguiente ejemplo,

```html
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a días');
?>
```

Sin embargo, no importa que fecha coloque, en el echo me muestra siempre "+6015 días", ¿cual puede ser el problema?,

Muchisimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esta respuesta.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime("2009-10-11");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("2009-10-13");
$resultado = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $resultado->format('%R%a días');
```

Comment: lo mismo estimado, lo agregue y me muestra "6015 days"

Comment: Agrega mas de tu codigo amigo para ver el por que radica esos 6015 dias

Comment: cambie el echo $diff->days . ' days '; por echo $diff->format('%d días'), "<br>"; y ahora me muestra "2 días", el problema es que si le cambio el mes a uno, no me cuenta los días correspondientes, solo lo que falta entre el 11 y el 13

Comment: hice unos pequeños cambios en la respuesta intenta de nuevo

Comment: Lo mismo, por ejemplo: de 2009-10-11 a 2009-10-13 muestra "2 dias", pero si le cambio a 2009-09-11 y 2009-10-13 igual me muestra "2 días", no toma en cuenta el cambio de mes